# Name File base on CSV value

Tags: powershell, csv, split, rename

I am trying to break a CSV file into multiple files using powershell then renaming them base on a value in the CSV file.  This is what I have so far, but all it does is names the file base on the counter rather than the value in the CSV file.

````
$sourceCSV = "c:\01_daily.csv"

$startrow = 0

$counter = 1

while ($startrow -lt $item)

{

Import-CSV $sourceCSV | 
    select-object -skip $startrow -first 1 | 
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | 
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    Set-Content "c:\daily$($counter).csv";

$startrow += 1 ;

$counter++ ;

}
```[enter image description here][1]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.
````

Comment: [1] how do you want to generate the file name? _in detail,please! [*grin*]  [2] what are you trying to achieve? there are simpler ways to break a text file into chunks of "this many lines". for instance, `Get-Content` has a `-LineCount` parameter ...

Comment: I have a CSV file that has 14 cells.  I want the file name to be name after the 10 cell.  But in the 10 cell there is .pdf I don't need.  For example, Cell 10 is David.PDF.  I just need to name the new csv file to be name David.CSV.  I don't want the .PDF within the file name.
So the final document will be name after the 10th cell and contain all the information within the row.

Comment: PLEASE, add to your Question a sample of the 1st 3-5 lines of your input file, what you want sent to each of the output files, and how to name each output file. your current description seems to indicate sending only ONE line to each file and naming it after part of the value in the 10th column. _that does not match your posted code at all._ [*grin*]

Comment: PLEASE ... **_do not post pictures of data/errors/code_**. the reason for my request was to allow testing code against your requirements. do you really expect anyone to type in your data just to help you ... when you already have that data as _text_?

Answer (score 0):

Oh dudy you think way too complex (for most of the csv files)

Take a look on this:

```
$sourceCSV = "c:\01_daily.csv"

[array]$object = Import-Csv $sourceCSV

for($i=1;$i -le $object.length; $i++) {

    $object[$i-1] | Out-File ('c:\daily' + $counter + '.csv')

}
```